# MySQL column depending on another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL like this

```
ID  |  Attribute1  |  Attribute2
--- | ------------ | ------------
15  |  value1      | value2
```

and then I have another table like this:

```
ID  |  Attribute  
--- | ------------ 
15  |  value1
15  |  value2
```

Is there a way to have Attribute1 in table 1 to be choosable only among the corresponding values of the other table?

Let's do an example:

```
ID          |  Attribute
----------- |  -----------
 Apple      |  Red
 Apple      |  Yellow
 BlueBerry  |  Red
 BlueBerry  |  Blue

ID         |  Attribute1
---------------------------
Apple      |   Red
BlueBerry  |   Blue
```

I don't want to be possible to choose "blue" for the "Apple".

Comment: Sure. Select the "corresponding values" (you'll have to define what that means), and only propose these as choosable values.

Comment: thank you, but I need a hand on how to do this, please explain to me

Comment: You'll need to show some effort, and be much clearer on what you want to achieve. Define "corresponding value", in a precise way. Explain what kind of application you're doing, in which language. Show what you tried. Explain which concrete difficulty you're facing. All we know is that the values are corresponding in some way, and that the use must choose values.

Comment: Your example has a flaw. You must replace ID 1 by 'Apple' and 2 by 'BlueBerry' in the first table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_t1_attr1 FOREIGN KEY (id, attribute1)
                                              REFERENCES table2 (id, attribute);
```

Thus you are only allowed to enter id/attribute pairs that exist in table1.